# Qt/Qml TextField receives keystroke twice when creating SDL window on macOS

Tags: macos, qt, qml, sdl

I created a Qt application with QML which contains a TextField. If I call SDL_CreateWindow() to create a new SDL2 window, typing in the TextField will duplicate every character. For example, if I type "hello" in the TextField, it will show "hheelllloo".

This only occurs after the creation of the SDL window. Also, this happens only on macOS. I compile the same application on Windows and Linux, and this problem is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen a similar bug in my Mac game using Cocoa windows with SDL2 2.0.14.

If the text fields are in a modal window, you could,,as a workaround call, SDL_EventState(SDL_TEXTINPUT, SDL_DISABLE) before displaying the modal window and call SDL_EventState(SDL_TEXTINPUT, SDL_ENABLE) when it closes.

With a non-modal window, you could try disabling the SDL text input when the window becomes active and enable when inactive.

Hope that helped.

Hopefully someone will fix this bug soon. I may look into it myself at some point soon. Note that I am not an SDL maintainer.